# Sum all the child level data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement where I need to sum up all the child of a node.

[image]

And the Output should be

```
D023343 120
D022959 120
D023375 50
D035738 10
D024481 0
```

I tried using diff queries but it is not getting the required . Kindly help

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.child achild,b.child bchild,a.parent aparent,b.parent bparent,a.sales,b.sales
 FROM TEST a,TEST b
WHERE a.CHILD='D023375')
where aparent!=bchild
and achild=bparent
```

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for but... if it's traversing the child chain, the output you show (as expected output) doesn't make sense, as your sums are inconsistent. As written, this is very unclear. Please edit accordingly. (and no need to tell people to help)

Comment: Why do you want output 50 on the middle line? Should it not be 60?

Answer (score 2):

Use a hierarchical query to traverse the hierarchy and `CONNECT_BY_ROOT()` to reference the top of the hierarchy - you can then use that to group the query to get the totals of the descendants.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0360c/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table( parent, child, sales ) AS
SELECT 'D023343', 'D022959',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D022959', 'D023375', 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D023375', 'D035738', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D035738', 'D024481', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT root,
       SUM( sales ) AS total_sales
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( parent ) AS root,
         sales
  FROM   your_table
  CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent
)
GROUP BY root
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0360c/3/0)**:

```
|    ROOT | TOTAL_SALES |
|---------|-------------|
| D023375 |          60 |
| D035738 |          10 |
| D023343 |         120 |
| D022959 |         120 |
```

If you want the leaf children that have no sales then you will need to do something like appending

```
UNION ALL
SELECT child, 0 FROM your_table
```

to the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive common table expression as defined in the [SQL-99 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999#Common_table_expressions_and_recursive_queries). Oracle calls this [recursive subquery factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2). You'll also need to do something to get the last record with 0 sales in the result, since there is no record that explicitly defines that sales amount.

Here is how such a query would look:

```
with base(parent, child, sales) as (
    select parent, child, sales
    from   tbl
    union all -- add the 0 sales records
    select child, null, 0
    from   tbl
),
rec(parent,child,sales) as ( -- recursive query
    select parent, child, sales
    from   base
    union all
    select rec.parent, base.child, base.sales
    from   base
    inner join rec on base.parent = rec.child
)
select   parent, sum(sales)
from     rec
group by parent
order by 1
```

NB: this syntax is supported as of Oracle 11g Release 2.